# CSS Selector HTML with Scrapy Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to make a web crawler to pull some information from Yahoo Finance as a personal Project. However, on the analysis page of Yahoo finance I can't pull a particular value. The HTML seems complicated to me, could I get some guidance?

```
class yhcrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yahoo'
    
    start_urls = [f'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/{t}/analysis?p={t}' for t in tkrs]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        filename = 'stock_growths.csv'
        
        l = response.css('div#YDC-Col1>div>div>div>div>div>section>table>tbody>tr>td#431::text').extract()
        print(l)
```

this is what I am trying

```
l = response.css('div#YDC-Col1>div>div>div>div>div>section>table>tbody>tr>td#431::text').extract()
```

and I am getting an empty results of

```
2021-04-18 15:12:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/M/analysis?p=M> (referer: None)
[]
```

The value I am trying to get is on the highlighted line, -11.82%
[image]

Comment: You wanna specify the exact value of an item available in that site in order for others to help you.

Comment: @SIM i added the value, -11.82%. Please advise

Comment: I don't know which ticker you are using, so the value in the image is useless. What value you wish to grab, if you consider this [link](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/aapl/analysis?p=aapl)? Beware that the value in there are not static, so specify by the field name, as in `Current Year`, `Next Year` e.t.c.

Comment: @sim growth estimate for the next 5 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class YahoofinanceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yahoofinance'
    start_urls = ['https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/aapl/analysis?p=aapl']
    
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    } 

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.xpath("//td[./span][contains(.,'Next 5 Years')]/following-sibling::td/text()").getall()
        yield {"item":item}
```